# Trouble laying out GridView contents?

Tags: xaml, microsoft-metro

I have this grid-view loading dynamic content correctly. However I can't quite figure out how to make it fill how I want. I want the content to start in the upper left corner and then create instance going downward until no more can fit (This should be 4) then start back at the top to the right of the original item.

The maxRowsOrCols property give me the behavior I desire, but I will definitely be exceeding 4 columns.

Please teach me.

Comment: Can you post the XAML which you have? And perhaps an image of what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an ItemsPanel with the WrapGrid. The Orientation property is Horizontal or Vertical first. This should allow you to set your layout as required, depending on screen size and ItemTemplate.

```
<GridView.ItemsPanel>
   <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <WrapGrid MaximiumRowsOrColumns="4" Orientation="Vertical"/>
   </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</GridView.ItemsPanel>
```

Comment: Brett, your answer worked perfectly. Thanks so much. I had the Max... property set but the orientation but it was capping the number of columns I could have without the orientation property set to vertical. Thanks!